# Pass method in a class as argument

Tags: c++

I have a class like this

```
class Keyboard
{
public:
    Keyboard(void);
    ~Keyboard(void);
    void SetHook(HINSTANCE hInstance);
    LRESULT CALLBACK keyboardHookProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
};


LRESULT CALLBACK Keyboard::keyboardHookProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    bool bControlKeyDown=0;
    bool caps = GetKeyState(VK_CAPITAL) < 0;

...

void Keyboard::SetHook(HINSTANCE hInstance)
{
    KeyboardHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, Keyboard::keyboardHookProc, hInstance, NULL);
}
```

But the statement

```
KeyboardHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, Keyboard::keyboardHookProc, hInstance, NULL);
```

Result in compile error

```
Error   7   error C3867: 'Keyboard::keyboardHookProc': function call missing argument list; use '&Keyboard::keyboardHookProc' to create a pointer to member
```

If I change to '&Keyboard::keyboardHookProc' it also error, also when I cast to '(HOOKPROC) &Keyboard::keyboardHookProc' it also error

Anyone please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is common mistake for C-callbacks.

`Keyboard::keyboardHookProc` must be static.

[UPDATE]

You must find some other way to get `Keyboard` object to this static method if you want to operate on `Keyboard` object in `static Keyboard::keyboardHookProc`. If you have one `Keyboard` you might use `singleton` pattern, If not then every static method must have its own `Keyboard` object.

[UPDATE2]

One of the way to link object with global function is by template object reference. But this work only for global objects:

```
class Keyboard
{
public:
    Keyboard();
    ~Keyboard(void);
    LRESULT keyboardHookProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
};

LRESULT Keyboard::keyboardHookProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
}
// global function interface 
template <Keyboard& k>
LRESULT CALLBACK keyboardHookProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
   return k.keyboardHookProc(nCode, wParam, lParam);
}


Keyboard k; // global keyboard

int main()
{
   // this works
   SetWindowsHookEx(0, keyboardHookProc<k>, NULL, NULL);
}
```

Comment: can't I pass callback method from normal method not static method? is there any reason?

Comment: "Non static" members have an implicit "this" parameter since one way or another they have to know which object to operate on, and C callbacks simply aren't prepared to deal with this. Also, a "pointer to member function" can be somewhat complicated, like when multiple inheritance is used.

Comment: To call member method one need object to call this method on behalf this object: `(object.*normalMethod)(args)`. Without object calling this method is not possible. For static method no object is required - they are more like ordinary C function which are originally expected here.

Comment: oh thank you so much everyone for the help and explanation, I am making it static and it works now.

Comment: @JohnKenedy just an update: I did not notice that passing `this` of type `Keyboard*` is not possible to `SetWindowsHookEx`. You must use some global variable of type `Keyboard` instead,